# Swift: prepareForSegue with two different segues

Tags: xcode, swift, segue

I have 2 `UIButtons` on a view.
Each of them are linked to 2 different views.
They have to pass different data depending which button you just tapped.

I know there is different way to `segue` but I want to use the `prepareForSegue` version for each (seems more clear for me to have the `segue` drawn on the storyboard and some code to explain what happened).

I tried this...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue != "historySegue") {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultViewController
        controller.match = self.match
    } else {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! HistoryViewController
        controller.history = self.history
    }
}


@IBAction func showHistory(sender: UIButton) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("historySegue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func match(sender: UIButton) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("matchSegue", sender: self)
}
```

But I got an error when I click the buttons

> (lldb)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take out your IBActions (making sure to delete them in the Connections Inspector via the right side bar in the Interface Builder as well as in your code). For the segues, just use the Interface Builder, make sure both segue's identifiers are correct, then try this prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "matchSegue" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultViewController
        controller.match = self.match
    } else if segue.identifier == "historySegue" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! HistoryViewController
        controller.history = self.history
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works now !

I dont need and action using prepareForSegue. The storyboard handle the action via the segue !

Answer (score 4):

You could switch it...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
        case "matchSegue":
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultViewController
            controller.match = self.match
        case "historySegue":
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! HistoryViewController
            controller.history = self.history
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got : `Binary operator ~= cannot be applied to operand of type String and String?`

Comment: @Ragnar Ah, identifier is optional will update. Edited

Answer (score 1):

You should compare the `segue.identifier` with the string not segue:

`segue.identifier == "historySegue"`

It won't fix your problem but it helps later.

I believe you have added an breakpoint and your app just stop at it. Remove the breakepoint and it will work.

Comment: Yes that's right I forgot this thanks. But onClick I still have this error
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'historySegue'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'`

Comment: It means that you choose Push segue but this kind of segue can be use with UINavigationControlle. Change the segue to modal or embed the view controller into navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

***prepareForSegue with two different segues***
**when you click on button uialert controller will show it will give you three options 1. physical, 2. online and 3. cancel.**

```
@objc func twoSegues(sender : UIButton) {
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Update Request", message: "Are you sure to update the record!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] (UIAlertAction) in

            if(serviceType == "physical") {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "physical", sender: self?.myArray[id!].serviceID)


                 }
            }
             if(serviceType == "online") {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "online", sender: self?.myArray[id!].serviceID)
                 }
            }
        })
        let no = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(yes)
        alert.addAction(no)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to navigate different segues in **objective C** you need to follow these actions.

1. **Click on the actual segue** on storyboard
2. Go to attribute inspector and **rename the identifier** of the segue
3. **customize the code** as following, here's an example:

   ```
   -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueNumberOne"]){
       YourViewController *functionalityViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
       functionalityViewController.someProperty = someValue;
       NSLog(@"move to segue number 1");
   }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueNumberTwo"]){
       NSLog(@"move to segue number 2");
   }
   ```