# How can I keep a level unlocked after moving from multiple other view controllers?

Tags: swift

I'm building a guessing game. I would like to know how I can keep level2 unlocked after finishing from level1 and moving to other view controllers such as the main menu. I tried using a bool value to open and close the level but after I move out of the levelselect_VC, and back into it, it locks itself back. How should I write the program?

Comment: Core Data https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1

Comment: If you don't care about persistence when the app closes, use prepareForSegue() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164654/passing-object-with-prepareforsegue-swift

Comment: I have a view controller that has multiple options to move to different VCs. Is there a way I can prepareForSegue() for particular VCs? @Shades

Comment: Absolutely, use separate identifiers for each. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457300/swift-prepareforsegue-with-two-different-segues . But note that this is good for passing the state of the level while the app is running. To save that state, you will need Core Data or User Defaults

Answer (score -2):

As going forward You can follow to a simple approach i.e create segues onto different view controller's and depending on lock/unlock status ,you can performSegueWithIdentifier method .

As you come back you can use to 2 things first one NOTIFICATION second one DELEGATION before pop view controller simply "post a notification" confirming that level 2 is unlocked don't show it and you can achieve the same with delegates.