# Using "OR" constructor in Segue - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[Loads of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457300/swift-prepareforsegue-with-two-different-segues) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303485/can-i-use-multiple-segues-with-one-uitableviewdelegate) and many more) about conditional segues where some different functionality is triggered but what I'm trying to do is simply use the OR operator to say "if segue destination is this OR this, then go here" (values to be passed etc remaining the same).

I'm trying this :

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
//if destination is VC1 OR VC2...

    if let destVC = segue.destination as?
    FavouriteDetailViewController || FavouriteExerciseDetailViewController

//... then pass the values as specified 

    destVC.favouriteWorkoutPassed = workoutToPass
    destVC.favouriteObjectPassed = favouriteObjectToPass
    }
```

As I thought the || would act as an "OR" operator but I'm getting error of `Optional type 'FavouriteDetailViewController?' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead`

Any help appreciated thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disjunctive set of types (an "OR"ing of multiple types) is expressed in Swift as a protocol.

Create a new protocol with the necessary properties/methods:

```
protocol SomeProtocol { // FIXME: Name me properly
    var favouriteWorkoutPassed: { get set }
    var favouriteObjectPassed: { get set }
}
```

Extend the desired types to conform to this protocol:

```
extension FavouriteDetailViewController: SomeProtocol {}
extension FavouriteExerciseDetailViewController: SomeProtocol {}
```

Cast to the protocol type:

```
// ...

if let destVC = segue.destination as? SomeProtocol
    destVC.favouriteWorkoutPassed = workoutToPass
    destVC.favouriteObjectPassed = favouriteObjectToPass
}

// ...
```

Comment: this is great thanks - do the extensions just go in the code on their own in the 'sending' VC? and where it says "get set" - what is that looking for?

Comment: It's a simple protocol requirement. It's looking for conforming types to have stored or computed properties with those names. I presume that both view controllers already had them, hence why I didn't add any body to the extensions

Comment: thanks - i think i'm nearly there with this - but I'm now getting "Cannot assign to property: 'destVC' is a 'let' constant" in the casting section - any ideas?

Comment: You'll probably want to constrain the protocol to only be applicable to classes, particularly `UIViewController`. `protocol SomeProtocol: UIViewController { ...`

Comment: sorry I'm trying this.... protocol SeguePreparation : UIViewController and getting the error  "Non-class type 'SeguePreparation' cannot inherit from class 'UIViewController'"

Comment: @nc14 Ah. I thought that a protocol would implicitly constrained to class types if was constrained to a class type. I was mistaken, so you'll have to make it explicit: `protocol SeguePreparation: class, UIViewController { ...`

Comment: when i try this... "protocol SeguePreparation: class, UIViewController {" I get the same error "Non-class type 'SeguePreparation' cannot inherit from class 'UIViewController'" + another one "Redundant layout constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'" - sorry thanks for helping!

Comment: Gah, this is hard without actually being able to play with it myself. `protocol SeguePreparation: class` should be sufficient. Optionally, to get access to common `UIViewController` functionality, you can do `protocol SeguePreparation: class where Self: UIViewController`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173423/discussion-between-nc14-and-alexander).